# how to integrate twilio php video with codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, twilio

I am trying use twilio video in a codeigniter.

(1) in config.php added this 
$config['composer_autoload'] = 'Twilio/autoload.php';

(2) added Twilio directory where my application folder is.
   folder structure
   application
   system
   Twilio

In My controller code

```
public function startRoom()
{

    use Twilio\Jwt\AccessToken;
    use Twilio\Jwt\Grants\VideoGrant;
    use Twilio\Jwt\Grants\SyncGrant;
    use Twilio\Jwt\Grants\IPMessagingGrant;

    $TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID = '';
    $TWILIO_API_KEY = '';
    $TWILIO_API_SECRET = '';
}
```

I am getting this error
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE) in D:\xampp\htdocs\video_code\application\controllers\Welcome.php on line 15

Line 15 is - use Twilio\Jwt\AccessToken;

Comment: You have to set namespaces to used classes [before controller class declaration](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php).

Comment: Thanks a lot @Tpojka. I have reinstalled composer and followed your advice now its working

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Tpojka had the right answer, I just wanted to follow up so that other people that might see this can see the answer.

The key is that, as the [documentation says](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php#language.namespaces.importing.scope):

> The use keyword must be declared in the outermost scope of a file (the global scope) or inside namespace declarations. This is because the importing is done at compile time and not runtime, so it cannot be block scoped.

So, you want to update your controller code to look like this:

```
use Twilio\Jwt\AccessToken;
use Twilio\Jwt\Grants\VideoGrant;
use Twilio\Jwt\Grants\SyncGrant;
use Twilio\Jwt\Grants\IPMessagingGrant;

public function startRoom()
{    
    $TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID = '';
    $TWILIO_API_KEY = '';
    $TWILIO_API_SECRET = '';

    // and so on...
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Amresh Feel free to [accept answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) that is solving exact issue.